# RaspAP with PiHole combine on one device

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi

What I am looking for is proper steps to replace the RaspAP ad-blocking with PiHole. There is very little information on this out on the net.

Specifically I would like to serve an independent access point (bridge mode is not good enough) with its own DNS providing clients with IPs. When connecting to this access point I want all data to go through pihole before out to the other DNS servers and internet on the eth0 side.

client(s) -> Access Point served from wlan0 of Pi -> DNS route for RaspAP to pihole on the same pi -> eth0 interface of pi to rest of internet

There is inadequate documentation about this on RaspAP:

https://docs.raspap.com/faq/#pihole

I can easily set up RaspAP with all features needed, but don't know how to plug in pihole into the chain as DNS provider for RaspAP (without breaking raspap dnsmasq or making it a bridge) before out to eth0. Also, I am aware that both RaspAP and PiHole use dnsmasq and have no idea how to solve that (which one should have control and how to set up).

Docker:

Using docker was also an option as pihole supports docker, and raspap also has a docker fork. This was even more difficult as RaspAP had no internet access when set up in docker and the networking in docker is beyond my understanding (the separate containers in that case make it just more difficult) on top of all that dnsmasq was still conflicting for some reason (it was impossible to run both containers at the same time), therefore I abandoned that route.

Comment: Pi-Hole is a DNS filtering (blackholing) server, so the only thing is does is act as a proxy for your DNS servers. no traffic will be processed by it, other than DNS queries. if the domain the user queries for is not on the blocklist, it just forwards the request up to the configured DNS server. DNS servers are specified by the Client, not by the network, so there is nothing to "plug-in". you just need to make sure your clients are using the pi-hole servers IP address as their DNS server. Usually you will use DHCP to configure the clients on your network to use the server you want.

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly what I want to avoid, there are too many devices to manually set the DNS on all of them. Ideally in this case the RaspAP is the client (including every connected device on it). Everything connected to the Pi should be filtered by PiHole running on the same pi. If it would be possible to "just buy another raspberry to run pihole" I would, it would be simple to set the second pi as DNS for RaspAP, but everyone knows that there is a shortage.

Comment: @Gerge No one asked you to buy another Pi. What Frank meant was you can't stop the AP clients from setting their DNS server to one other than your Pi(-Hole) (although you can set up some nasty DNAT, I suppose). The real problem in your question doesn't look more than changing the port Pi-Hole listens to / disabling the DNS forwarding function in dnsmasq. Not to mention that Pi-Hole can be set up in a docker container.

Comment: @TomYan, thanks I misunderstood that. I still think that Pihole is a bit hard to set-up like this (I also tried docker, and had many other issues) even in docker there were conflicts with dnsmasq.

Comment: I don't know anything about the internals of PiHole, but I suppose you could run it in a separate network namespace or container under an independent LAN IP and put that for DNS in RaspAP's DHCP configuration, no?

Comment: Ops, sorry. I missed some of the comments. So, if you already tried docker, I suggest you include that attempt in you question together with what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround/alternative solution. AdGuard is better described in RaspAP documentation and clear enough to set it up. In the end PiHole was too much of a problem to set up while AdGuard just works.

Both RaspAP and AdGuard are on the same machine. RaspAP uses AdGuard as upstream DNS. There are no conflicts with dnsmasq either.

1. install AdGuard using the command on github
2. set adguard listening port to 127.0.0.1:5300
3. set RaspAP to use AdGuard at 127.0.0.1#5300 in DHCP/Advanced

source:https://docs.raspap.com/faq/#adguard